# Event handler when user manually shutsdown system

Tags: macos, qt, macos-carbon

I need a event handler when ever shutdown message is send to system.
Can anyone help?

When ever we try to shutdown a system, and if any dialog box is open shutdown process terminates. I don't want this to happen in my application. i.e if any dialog box is open from my application and I try to shutdown my system then it should not block shutdown process. Is this implementation possible?

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, look at NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

try overriding [QApplication::commitData](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/qapplication.html#commitData) it should be called whenever user shuts down the system and your application is still running.

> This function deals with session
>   management. It is invoked when the
>   QSessionManager wants the application
>   to commit all its data.
>
> Usually this means saving all open
>   files, after getting permission from
>   the user. Furthermore you may want to
>   provide a means by which the user can
>   cancel the shutdown.

below is an example (never tried it with macs; though works fine on my ubuntu):

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QSessionManager>

class MyApplication : public QApplication
{
public:
    MyApplication(int &argc, char **argv);
    virtual void commitData(QSessionManager& sm);
};

MyApplication::MyApplication(int &argc, char **argv):
        QApplication(argc, argv)
{
    //???
}

void MyApplication::commitData(QSessionManager& sm)
{
    // do smth here....    
    QApplication::commitData(sm);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

hope this helps, regards